# OpenLayers Cluster Source does not return (source.getSource()) the exact original given Source

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, openlayers

I have a VectorLayer with the original source as VectorSource.
In the application, there is a toggle that allows the users to enable/disable clustering features of a VectorLayer.

Basically, on toggle ON, a code similar as follows run:

```js
layer.setSource(new Cluster({ source: layer.getSource() }));
```

And on toggle OFF:

```js
const source = layer.getSource();
if (source instanceof Cluster) {
    layer.setSource(source.getSource());
}
```

So far everything's working well. The problem arises when the original source which is supposed to come back from `source.getSource()` appears to be not exactly as what I've initially given it (`...{ source: layer.getSource() }`)

**How do I say that?** 
We've some features (not talking about OpenLayers features) for the users to play with the style of features on a VectorLayer. For example, changing their colors, toggling their labels, assigning pictures, etc. Before a user does any interaction with the explained toggle above, all these style operations are fast and smooth. However, after the interaction, all these operations take about 10-15 times more time. It's a massive performance issue.

I've been investigating this problem for a few days now. I can't seem to understand why this is the case. In some forum threads I've read generally vectors are not efficient to handle +1000 features on the client-side. But for me and our users, everything's fast enough until the clustering toggle goes on and off (meaning that the very created original source has been replaced at least once).

It seems like something gets lost during the replacement of the sources which has a noticeable impact on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Call `source.setSource(null);` on the cluster source when it is removed.
Otherwise the clustersource will live on as long as the source exists, and each time the source fires a change event it will cluster the features.
https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_source_Cluster-Cluster.html

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it. However, I can see this method was added in v6.3.0. We're still using v5. Is there any alternative way or it's our time to migrate?

Comment: The setSource method was added to solve this exact problem. To work around it you can create a new VectorSource instead of reusing the one used by the ClusterSource.